# Which Oracle jdbc jars are required

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc, jar

I am seeing many jars files in Oracle jdbc download page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

I have downloaded the following drivers:

1. ojdbc6.jar
2. ojdbc6_g.jar
3. ojdbc6dms.jar
4. ojdbc6dms_g.jar
5. orai18n.jar

I am trying to use it in my Tomcat 7 version. I added all these jar files to $CATALINA_HOME/lib folder but after couple of days my Tomcat throws this error:

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverterOGS.getInstance(I)Loracle/i18n/text/converter/CharacterConverter;
    oracle.sql.converter.CharacterConverterFactoryOGS.make(CharacterConverterFactoryOGS.java:40)
    oracle.sql.CharacterSetWithConverter.getInstance(CharacterSetWithConverter.java:135)
    oracle.sql.CharacterSetFactoryThin.make(CharacterSetFactoryThin.java:195)
    oracle.sql.CharacterSet.make(CharacterSet.java:555)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.init(DBConversion.java:236)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.<init>(DBConversion.java:133)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1704)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:385)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:564)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:251)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:29)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:563)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    DB.getOracleConnection(DB.java:13)
    IndexDAO.displayNewsTicker(IndexDAO.java:54)
    SiteTemplate.newsTicker(SiteTemplate.java:256)
    SiteTemplate.headerButtons(SiteTemplate.java:226)
    Index.doGet(Index.java:55)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

my oracle version is `SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production` I searched a lot but mostly experts are talking about duplicate or wrong version of jdbc drivers. I doubled check both suggestion but same problem.

Now question came in my mind that I may adding in my tomcat lib folder wrong jars. I mean may be I need 1-2 jar files but adding 5 aforementioned jdbc jars that may have duplicate classes.

Please advise

Comment: See description of `ojdbc6_g.jar`: ***Same as ojdbc6.jar** except compiled with "javac -g" and contains tracing code.* --- See description of `ojdbc6dms.jar`: ***Same as ojdbc6.jar**, except that it contains instrumentation to support DMS and limited java.util.logging calls.* --- So remove all but one of `ojdbc6.jar`, `ojdbc6_g.jar`, `ojdbc6dms.jar`, `ojdbc6dms_g.jar`. They are all the "same",

Comment: Your error seems to indicate that the `orai18n.jar` files is not the same version as the `ojdbc6.jar`. You should verify that. It could also mean that you have duplicate jars of that.

Comment: @Andreas you mean that I remove all the five files including i18n.jar I mentioned in my question except ojdbc6.jar. am I right?

Comment: I meant what I said. You remove 3 of the files (3 = "all but one" of 4). I don't know if you need `orai18n.jar`, so you could try removing it too. I've never needed it myself.

Comment: Andreas thank you very much. Can you please add your comments as answer so that I mark it correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need this one: **ojdbc6.jar**.

- **ojdbc*.jar** - all the classes to support basic functionality for the Thin and OCI drivers
- **ojdbc*_g.jar** - same as ojdbc*.jar except compiled with the -g option to include debugging information and with java.util.logging calls included.
- **ojdbc*dms.jar** - same as ojdbc*.jar except includes code to support Oracle Dynamic Monitoring Service (DMS). Also includes some JDBC logging support. This file can only be used when dms.jar is also in the classpath. The dms.jar file is not shipped as part of the RDBMS product. It is only available as part of the Oracle Application Server product.
- **ojdbc*dms_g.jar** - same as ojdbc*dms.jar except compiled with the -g option to include debugging information and with full JDBC logging support.
- **orai18n.jar** - contains the configuration information to support all Oracle character sets in Advanced Data Types (objects). If the database character set is one other than UCS2,ASCII, ISO_LATIN_1, UTF8 and AL32UTF8 and the application uses ADTs, then you must include this file in your classpath.

Taken from here: [Oracle JDBC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jdbc-faq-090281.html)

Comment: I have ojdbc8 on my classpath. When I also try to import ojdbc8, it gives me "class is sealed" exception( I am using jdk17). And when I remove I get this error. What to do now?