# package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist in javaBeans

Tags: java, oracle, javabeans

It keeps on telling me the oracle driver doesn't exist. 
But I have moved all the files to connect with oracle like below.[image]

and also the classes12.jar inside Tomcat8.5\lib.
EnrollMgr.java:6: error: package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;

I also have package oracle.jdbc.pool does not exist errors too.
What should I do?

Here is the code Below. 
          package AttendanceBean;

```
 import java.sql.*;
 import java.util.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.*;
import attendanceBean.*;

public class AttendanceBean {

private OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ocpds = null;
private PooledConnection pool = null;

public AttendanceBean() {
    try {

        ocpds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();

        ocpds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@210.94.199.20:1521:dblab");
        ocpds.setUser("ST2017113504");
        ocpds.setPassword("ST2017113504");

        pool = ocpds.getPooledConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error : Connection Failed");
    }
}
public Vector getAttendanceList(String s_id, int c_id) {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Vector vecList = new Vector();

    try {
        conn = pool.getConnection();

        String mySQL = "select a.week_1 w1,a.week_2 w2,a.week_3 w3, a.week_4 w4, a.week_5 w5,a.week_6 w6, a.week_7 w7 , a.week_8 w8 from enroll e, attendance a, course c where e.s_id=? and e.c_id=? and e.c_id=c.c_id and e.c_id_no=c.c_id_no";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(mySQL);
        pstmt.setString(1, s_id);
        pstmt.setString(2, c_id);

        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Attendance att = new Attendance();
            vecList.add(rs.get_Attendance("w1"));
            vecList.add(rs.get_Attendance("w2"));
            vecList.add(rs.get_Attendance("w3"));
            vecList.add(rs.get_Attendance("w4"));
            vecList.add(rs.get_Attendance("w5"));
            vecList.add(rs.get_Attendance("w6"));
            vecList.add(rs.get_Attendance("w7"));
            vecList.add(rs.get_Attendance("w8"));
            vecList.add(att);
        }
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception" + ex);
    }

    return vecList;
}



}
```

Comment: Have you checked this ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218464/which-oracle-jdbc-jars-are-required